# Export to Excel assistance with Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I had built a Realtime plot of a model and want to export data in that plot to an excel sheet , I had created a dataset and put the variable name inside it , I used a function that returns nothing and in the body I put the following :

```
excelFile.writeDataSet(datasetHourly, sheetIndex, row, column);
excelFile.writeFile();
```

but after the run is complete , I go check the excel file and it's empty
what seems to be the error ?

Comment: Welcome to SOF! When asking a question, please try to provide all the relative information; including screenshots from your model. Can you please provide the screenshot of your Data Set properties? And when exactly do you run the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. However, the following works:

```
int column=1;
for (int row=1;row<101;row++){
    excelFile.writeDataSet(datasetHourly, 1, row, column);
    excelFile.writeFile();
}
```

You need to write this code to Main>Agent Actions>On Destroy.

[image]

You can adjust the loop as per your own requirements.

Comment: Thank you , should i close the run interface so data can be transferred to the excel  ?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to do this action at any given hour, just create an event, paste this code into it. And put the time whenever you want to run this action inside the evet.